# log4j.properties file to log4j2.xml conversion

Tags: java, log4j2

I am upgrading from log4j1.x to log4j-2.8.2
I am trying to convert my existing log4j.properties file to equivalent log4j2.xml.
My first question is can I write log4j2.proeprties file instead of log4j2.xml file?

I found some equivalent tags to log4j.proeprties file in log4j2.xml.
I did not find tags for the below lines. can anybody suggest on this?

```
# LoggerFactory for ESAPI to utilize Log4J
log4j.loggerFactory=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory
log4j.category.Default=ALL, CONSOLE, RollingFile2, edelivery
log4j.rootCategory=OFF

log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO
log4j.logger.IntrusionDetector=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: [Migrating from Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)

Answer (score 0):

**What i am sure is:**
See the last three lines:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO
log4j.logger.IntrusionDetector=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

I think in log4j.xml they should be instead of like these below:

```
<Logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>
<Logger name="IntrusionDetector" level="ERROR"/>
<Logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
```

**And what I am not sure is:**
these two lines:

```
log4j.category.Default=ALL, CONSOLE, RollingFile2, edelivery
log4j.rootCategory=OFF
```

I guess you have configured some appenders with the name in above line like:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE">
  other proerties....
</appender>
```

so i think you could try to use these in your log4j.xml:

```
<root>
  <appender-ref ref="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile2" />
  <appender-ref ref="edelivery" />
</root>
```

**And What I really don't know is:**

```
log4j.loggerFactory=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory
```

I Know nothing about esapi so i could not suggest how to deal with it, hope someone else to give more answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jian. :)

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: No. I researching on it.